# Can i switch to the original tone after the repeated part is over?

Tags: keyboard, organ

There is a repeated part in a song I'm playing, where I'm supposed to change the voices. It stays organ, but a different type both the times.

The thing is that after the repetition is over, the changed sound does not fit well and just the first organ sound (which is played the first time, before the repetition) suits better for the rest of the song.

So, can I again switch sounds??
Though it does not say so on the sheet...

Comment: What is the piece?

Answer (score 2):

You are the driver, you decide where and how to go! It sounds like it's someone's arrangement, and especially if it's a solo piece, you get to decide. You may want to revert to the original sound, you may decide to use a new one for the other part. It's up to you.

If it's playing with others, it may be a different kettle of fish, and maybe the bandleader has a say. That happens quite a lot in a big band I work with - I play a particular sound (I think it's appropriate), but the bandleader suggests (sometimes strongly!) that I try several others, till he's happy. After all, that's part of his job.

Comment: Yes, I understand. The thing is that this is an exam piece, I'm supposed to play it in the exam. So, I don't want to take any risk. The sheet does not say so, but the original tone sounds better, so I'll still do that. Thank you.

Comment: Any questions you have regarding exam expectations should be asked to the exam board. The guys there are often helpful. Or possibly your teacher.

Comment: @Ishan.J If it's unclear, the examiners won't penalize you for having a 'wrong' sound as long as your solution is musically good

Comment: Oh, yes. But, still I have this instinct to stick to the sheet as much as possible!! Though, if it is for better, I don't think it matters much, right??

Comment: To @Tim , I'm a self-taught learner and even the exam board teachers in my place aren't quick in answering questions. Rather I get faster and better answers here.